# python, pd.read_csv ripetitive importation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to import with

```
 pd.read_csv
```

a repetitive importation as
at first time I import

```
node_t1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N122')
node_t2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N122')
node_t3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N122')
```

but I need to import # times as N1, N2, ..., N121, N122
as the second time:

```
node_t1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N121')
node_t2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N121')
node_t3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N121')
```

and so on.

Other question, as you can see into the code there is a repetitive name (as 'N122')

```
node_t1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N122')
node_t2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N122')
node_t3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N122')
```

there is a simple method to substitute in the code 'N122' to 'N' as

```
node_t1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N')
node_t2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N')
node_t3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N')
```

so I keep the same code, like before, for each node and with other code I change only one time the node name (N122, N121,...).

There is a simple method to do this?

Comment: sorry, but I think this solution don't work properly because with the command ' pd.read_csv' it open a table with some rows and columns. 
So I need to separate the code step by step:

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using a [formatted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) string and a loop like:

```
def read_nodes(node_number):
    n1 = pd.read_csv('5mins/nodes/N%d' % node_number)
    n2 = pd.read_csv('10mins/nodes/N%d' % node_number)
    n3 = pd.read_csv('15mins/nodes/N%d' % node_number)
    return n1, n2, n3


for i in range(150):
    node_t1, node_t2, node_t3 = read_nodes(i)

    # process nodes for node i here
    ....
```